# jQuery UI not loading when lightning component embedded inside VF on console

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to use jQuery and jQuery UI in salesforce lightning component which is embedded inside VF page. This VF page is available on console for ex. `domain/my.salesforce.com/console`

When I run it I am able to load only jQuery version 3.2.1 inside this console, not other jquery versions are able to load.... fine  I am happy with it. but next step is to load the jQuery UI version which should be compatible with jQuery 3.2.1.

But I am getting below error when jQuery UI loads in such scenario : lightning component embedded inside vf which is shown on console.

**Jquery UI error:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: n[o].hasOwnProperty is not a function
throws at /resource/jQuery_UITEST:8:5049
```

what I found is jQuery v2.2.4 and jQuery UI - v1.11.2 works together well when use purely as lightning app but do not work when I embed this lightning component inside vf and that vf is part of console.

If you have any idea kindly provide your inputs.

Thanks,
Akki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered here:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/180535/jqueryui-inputinputindex-hasownproperty-is-not-a-function

Simply said: All external libs that use the function hasOwnProperty are not working (yet) because the function has not been added to the LockerService SecureWindow object. Using an older version of jquery UI solves it for now (version 1.11.4 is supported)

Answer (score 0):

When you embed lightning inside Visualforce, things do behave differently.  Have you looked in your browser's console to see what JavaScript errors are being thrown?  Typically you will see some related to CORS.
You then need to update your CORS settings in Salesforce to whitelist the URLS mentioned in the errors.
[Use CORS for Lightning Out](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/extend_code_cors.htm)

Comment: no this is not the problem.......... script is getting loaded but it's throwing mentioned error as I posted in the question